# Why do unspecified generics get inferred differently, simple call vs null-coalesce, in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-types

Why do `a` and `b` have different types in the below code?

```
function empty<T>() { return [] as T[] }

const defEmpty = empty()

function test1(abc: number[]|null) {
  const a = abc ?? defEmpty
  const b = abc ?? empty()
}
```

The the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAUwLYAcoE8A8AVAPgAoBKRAb0QCdkoQqkBtAXUQEMBnRPFxAXwCwAKGEQEHKIgAmyYAFEM2RAF4UirKWHDQkWAkRRkEgIxE2AIwgAuRGBCpzyKiwA+dgDbuy5YYkRiwCXYVdktEAH5w6VkFTCxff3FJcxCLCAiotDjNIUEhRC0hIA), I can see `a: unknown[]` and `b: number[]`.  I was expected them both to have the type `unknown[]`.

Comment: This doesn't have much to do with "`unknown` disappearing".  The difference in your two examples is that `defEmpty` is of type `unknown[]` because there's nowhere for the compiler to infer `T`.  But in `abc ?? empty()` the compiler uses [contextual typing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing) to infer that `T` should be `number` and so you get `number[]`.  Type inference is a set of heuristics and they don't always do what every developer wants; if you care you can specify the types yourself like `abc ?? empty<unknown>()`.

Comment: Does that answer your question?  If so I can write it up as an answer, but first could you [edit] the title so that it doesn't mention "`unknown` types disappearing" because that's not what's happening (or is at least misleading)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not provide explicit generic type in `empty()` call here:

```
const b = abc ?? empty()
```

But Typescript can infer that type from the expression - it knows that `abc` is of type `number[] | null` so it infers that type parameter for `empty` call is `number` (you can see it by the way in the playground by your link if you hover over `empty()`). So your line basically becomes:

```
const b = abc ?? empty<number>();
```

And as such b is also of type `number[]`. Note that omitting generic type parameter does not mean it will become `unknown`.

As for how exactly type inference works - as far as I know there is no strict specification. The last [specification version](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/main/doc/spec-ARCHIVED.md) is archived and no longer maintained. And there were [changes](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1186) to type inference rules compared to this archived specification. As such, the best source of information you have is [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html) which are pretty vague. The relevant section is called "Contextual Typing" and it describes in broad terms that Typescript is capable of inferring generic type parameter from context in many cases, but do not describe in strict terms how it works.

This case however seems pretty clear. On the left hand side of ?? expression you have expression of known type, so it makes sense to use that same type on the right hand side with omitted generic type parameter.

Comment: What are the rules for this type of forward-inferencing?  That's the bit I'm trying to figure out. I see it happen in some cases, but not clear where this is documented to be expected.

Comment: As far as I know, specification is outdated and no longer maintained. Actual docs, for example: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html, is not a strict specification and just describe in broad terms how it works. For example "Contextual typing applies in many cases. Common cases include arguments to function calls, right hand sides of assignments, type assertions, members of object and array literals, and return statements". So, "many cases" also includes this one.